# Problema al insertar estos valores en MYSQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código:

```
<?php

require_once "connection-mysql.php";

/*Si hay letra fuera.
Quitar espacios.
Si hay coma fuera
Si no vienen con 13 caracteres, meter 0 a la izquierda hasta que sean 13 caracteres.


*/




$archivo=fopen("articulos_erp.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo   
$arrayLineasDefinitivo=array();

while(!feof($archivo)){ //Voy leyendo el CSV

    $linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV y lo voy poniendo en formato UTF8
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea); //Aquí tengo mi array con los datos del CSV

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        if(!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito los ean que tengan alguna letra
                if(!preg_match("/,/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito las comas
                   
                    $arrayLineasSinEspacios=trim($arrayLineas[0]);
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=str_replace(" ", "", $arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    $numeroCaracteres=strlen($arrayLineasLimpio);
                    

                    switch($numeroCaracteres){

                        case 12:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 11:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 9:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="0000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="00000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break; 
                        case 7:
                            $arrayLineasLimpio="000000".$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            break;       
                    }

                    $arrayLineasLimpioInt = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $arrayLineasLimpio);
                   
                    if( preg_match("/^[0-9]{13}$/", $arrayLineasLimpioInt) ) {
                        $arrayLineasDefinitivo[]=$arrayLineasLimpioInt;
                    }



                    // var_dump($arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    //Si no vienen con 13 caracteres, meter 0 a la izq.
                    //quitar espacios
                }

        }
      }  
    
      

    }

    // echo "<pre>";
    // var_dump($arrayLineasDefinitivo[0]);
    // echo "SE REPITE";
    // echo "<br>";
    // echo "</pre>";  
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayLineasDefinitivo[0]');";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);

    if(!$resultado){
        echo "Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService);
    } 
?>
```

A ver, me funciona todo menos la sentencia SQL. Tengo el siguiente problema. Si lo ejecuto como está ahora, que está fuera del while, sólo me inserta el primer valor del array, no todos. Pero, sin embargo, si lo meto en el último corchete del while, me mete el primer valor, y luego claro, va a meter el primero y el segundo porque va recorriendo, y al intentar meter el primero de nuevo me dice que es un valor duplicado en la BBDD de MySQL y no me deja. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias, saludos.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

Estoy probando como mencionaron en respuestas con un contador. Este es el siguiente código:

```
      $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador]');";
      $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
      $contador++;
  
      if(!$resultado){
          echo "Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService);
      }
```

Debería funcionar, pero sin embargo, da el siguiente error: 'Undefined offset. INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES (''); Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY.

Entiendo que al recorrer intenta meter el mismo valor dos veces y por eso ocurre eso, pero en teoría no debería, ya que para eso le he puesto la variable $contador.

¿Alguna idea de en qué estoy fallando? Gracias, saludos.

Comment: esto es lo que queres meter en la db? arrayLineasLimpioInt?

Comment: arrayLineasDefinitivo es lo que quiero meter en la BD

Comment: USA `LPAD` en SQL

Answer (score 1):

tu problema es mas logico.

`if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío`

en esta parte solo estas tomando el dato que esta en la posicion 0 en esta deberia haber un autoincrementable o algo asi ya que el explode lo combierte en un array.

Comment: Un autoincrementable como un qué? un contador, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, lo he solucionado así:

```
    $contador=0;
    $longitud=count($arrayLineasDefinitivo);
    $valor=0;

    while($contador<$longitud){
      $valor=$arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador];

      if(!empty($valor)){ //Le meto otro control para campos vacíos
        $sql="INSERT INTO articulos_csv (`ean`) VALUES ('$arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador]');";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
        $contador++;
    
        if(!$resultado){
            echo "Error: ". $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService);
        }
      }
    }
```

Básicamente usando un contador y guardando en una variable aparte el valor de $arrayLineasDefinitivo[$contador] en cada iteración.